# iphone string manipulation

Tags: iphone, string

Coming across from vb.net to iphone. Im currently trying to iterate through a string to pull values out of it. I have the following example string:

Field1ExampleField2ExampleField1ExampleField2Example

So basically i want to loop through the string and put the Field1 and Field2 of each value into a list.

In VB i would:

while str <> ""
dim CurrentStringValue as string = ""
'SET THE CURRENTSTRINGVALUE TO BE  to 
'Remove that string from the looping string "str"
'Use substring to pull the values out of field1 and field2 and pump it into a list
end while

Any ideas on how this would basically be done in objective c?

Thanks

Comment: The example string got changed by stackoverflow.

"<Val><Field1>Field1Example</Field1><Field2>Field2Example</Field2></Val><Val><Field1>Field1Example</Field1><Field2>Field2Example</Field2></Val>"

Comment: Click on "edit" to correct the actual question

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to parse XML, you should look at [this link about XML parsing in iPhone applications](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

**From the first version of your question:**

You can try this:

```
NSString *allValuesString = @"NField1ExampleField2ExampleField1ExampleField2Example";
NSArray *allValues = [allValuesString componentsSeparatedByString:@"Example"];
```